# Often Misused: Authentication - Fortify

Tags: java, xss, owasp, fortify

when i do scan using fortify i have got 5 vulnerabilities like "Often Misused: Authentication" at the below code. For this do we have any fix to avoid this issue.

```
  this.localAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
```

When we call the `.getLocalHost()` fortify complaining as an issue.

Answer (score 4):

It despends on how you're using this address.  If you're using it to determine whether you have access to an application within a certain range of addresses, for example, it is an issue.  Address resolution protocol (ARP) poisining is one of the most basic tools in an attackers toolkit.

If you're only using this to log a machine name for convenience purposes than you're probably ok.

Comment: I am using

 private void initMachineName(){
  try {
   machineName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
is it fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the recomendation from fortify, but if you need to access the localhost by this, I would suggest a better look on your architecture, because it can be flawed.